# How to integrate here maps with dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, heremaps

Trying to integrate here maps with dash. here is my dash code.

```
    import dash
    import dash_html_components as html
    
    external_stylesheets = ['https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css']
    
    external_scripts = 
    [
       'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js',
       'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js',
       'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js',
       'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js'
    ]
    
    app = dash.Dash(name, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, external_scripts=external_scripts)
    
    app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id=‘map’)
    ])
    
    if name == “main”:
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

folder path:

- main :

  - assets

    - demo.css
      – demo.js
      – style.css
  - heredashpolyline.py
    I am following this: [drawing a polyline on here maps]
    https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/geoshapes/polyline-on-the-map